# How to update object dto in dbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For example, I have function in repository to add images to dto:

```
public async Task AddImagesAsync(List<Guid> imageIds, ProductDto product)
{
    await _dbContext.ProductImages.AddRangeAsync(imageIds.Select(x => new ProductImage { ImageId = x, ProductId = product.Id }));

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

How to create function for Update on similar way?

Comment: Don't use EF Entity Objects as DTOs. Even though they have similar (if not identical) member properties, they represent different things.

Comment: You don't need either function. In fact, this function is a **critical** bug that breaks EF Core. DbContext isn't a database connection, its a Unit-of-Work that caches all modifications and persists them in a single transaction when you call `SaveChangesAsync`. Your `AddImagesAsync` method can easily execute 3 deles and update 40 products

Comment: Assuming that `ProductDto` is a DTO and not an EF entity class, then you can use AutoMapper to handle most of the tedium (though I prefer to write DTO mappings manually).

Comment: @Dai mapping has nothing to do with this question. DTO is a term used for a lot of things, not just HTTP API DTOs. This code has far more critical problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure it does: the OP wants to map data in a `ProductDto` to their `ProductImage` entity object(s) somehow. AutoMapper can handle that. Also, the context of the OP's code looks very much like an ASP.NET MVC `Controller` action method (and honestly, people only ever ask this level of question about EF in a web context). In current parlance I've only ever seen "DTO" used to refer to types used as web-service DTO contracts - it's not like people are using CORBA DTOs.

Comment: If you keep using such methods you lose the transactional and disconnected behavior of EF Core. DbContext *doesn't* keep a connection open unless it needs to load data or persist changes. Since you can't depend on DbContext.SaveChanges for transactional integrity any more, you'll have to create explicit database transactions. In turn, this means you need to keep the database connection open for a very long time, accumulating locks and blocking other operations. You could end up deadlocking your application with just a few (as in 2) concurrent operations.

Comment: @Dai the OP didn't say anything about web applications, much less MVC.  DTO is also used to refer to the objects loaded from storage to differentiate them from business entities, especially when talking about DDD. When used properly, a real Repository will map the storage DTOs to domain entities and return the aggregate roots. In the "generic repository" antipattern shown here, the "repository" returns the DTOs of the entities

Comment: @Dai in fact, I'm sure the OP is already using AutoMapper further up because "best practices". I'd guess this is indeed a web app using the whole "Clean best practices" boilerplate.

Comment: @Kristina In the end, this question needs more focus, because it is basically asking: how do I update an entity from dto values using EF? That's too broad to answer. Too many alternatives. I suggest you propose a method and add it to your question (if, of course, you still have a question then).

Answer (score 0):

Your code to simply insert ProductImages is "ok" as an isolated operation, although it doesn't account for the possibility that duplicate image IDs could be associated to the same Product. (not necessarily in the same list, but adding an image reference in the list to a product where that product already references that image ID) If you want to update the product's images to reflect the passed in list, adding if they don't exist or removing ones that are no longer in the list then the approach I would use would be a bit different:

```
public async Task UpdateImagesAsync(List<Guid> imageIds, ProductDto product)
{
    var product = await _dbContext.Products
        .Include(x => x.ProductImages)
        SingleAsync(x => x.ProductId == product.Id);

    var existingIds = product.ProductImages.Select(x => x.ImageId).ToList();

    var imageIdsToAdd = imageIds.Except(existingIds).ToList();
    var imageIdsToRemove = existingIds.Except(imageids).ToList();

    var imagesToAdd = imageIds.Select(x => new ProductImage { ImageId = x}).ToList();
    var imagesToRemove = product.ProductImages.Where(x => imageIdsToRemove.Contains(x.ImageId)).ToList();

    if(imagesToRemove.Any())
       product.ProductImages.RemoveRange(imagesToRemove);
    if(imagesToAdd.Any())
       product.ProductImages.Addrange(imagesToAdd);

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This assumes the Product has a collection of ProductImages mapped as a navigation property with a PK being composed of the ProductId and ImageId. This might need to be tweaked to reflect your particular mapping, but to perform an update would involve loading the current product and it's related images, determining which references to add, vs. which references to remove. You may also want to add a Distinct on the passed in imageIds to ensure duplicate IDs sent into the request don't gunk things up.